# Spring cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans' and similar problems

Tags: java, xml, spring, jboss

since some days I got this strange problem with spring 4.3.3 . On deploy (both in DEV and in a Test environment the server produces alternately these 2 errors

**Error #1.** It comes when I'm over a proxy or an internet connection is not available

```
Ignored XML validation warning: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 8; columnNumber: 108; schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
```

and then

```
 Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 8 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/jboss-as-spring-mvc-context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 8; columnNumber: 108; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
```

**Error #2.** It comes when a connection is available (or was available)

```
 JBWEB000289: Servlet pdaServlet threw load() exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/context]
```

Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/jboss-as-spring-mvc-context.xml]

Independently from the exception thrown the system **WORKS** anyway, probably due to the fact that the spring configuration is split in 3 files and the first 2 load correctly. But I'd like to understand what's happening.
I've seen a LOT of responses on both these topics, but none applies to my case.

Here's my configuration:

**WEB.XML**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
         metadata-complete="true">

 <display-name>Java EE 6 Starter Application</display-name>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml,
                classpath:/META-INF/spring/infrastructure.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.myCloud.pda.listener.InitContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>pdaServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/jboss-as-spring-mvc-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <multipart-config>
   <location>/</location>
   <max-file-size>734003200</max-file-size>
   <max-request-size>2936012800</max-request-size>
   <file-size-threshold>0</file-size-threshold>
  </multipart-config>
  </servlet>
  ...
```

**applicationContext.xml (loads OK)**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="locations" value="file:${JbossApps.confPath}/pda/pda.properties"/>
</bean>

<bean id="eventListenerBean" class="com.myCloud.initializer.MultimediaApplicationListener" />


<context:component-scan base-package="com.myCloud.pda.mvc"/>

....
```

**Infrastructure.xml (Loads OK)**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
         xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd">

    <!-- JDNI name for EntityManagerFactory is defined in src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml -->
    <jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="java:jboss/pda/persistence" id="entityManagerFactory"
                     expected-type="javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory" />

....
```

**jboss-as-spring-mvc-context.xml (Exception)**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">


     <context:component-scan base-package="com.myCloud.pda.mvc"/>


    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    .....
```

**POM.XML**

```
  <properties>
                <!-- Spring version -->
        <version.spring>4.3.3.RELEASE</version.spring>
        <version.poi>3.17</version.poi>
        <!-- Spring Third Party dependencies -->
        <version.aopalliance>1.0</version.aopalliance>

 .....
 <dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>

  ....
  <!-- Spring dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${version.spring}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
            <version>${version.spring}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${version.spring}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${version.spring}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${version.spring}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${version.spring}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${version.spring}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${version.spring}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${version.spring}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${version.spring}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${version.spring}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${version.spring}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${version.spring}</version>
        </dependency>

       .....
            </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
     <dependencies>
      .....
  <!-- Import Spring dependencies, these are either from community or versions
        certified in WFK2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
    </dependency>
     -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Additional Notes

1- When having the error #1 I see from the startup logs this message when processing **applicationContext.xml**

```
Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml]
23:47:22,797 DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 23) Using JAXP provider [__redirected.__DocumentBuilderFactory]
23:47:22,813 DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.PluggableSchemaResolver] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 23) Loading schema mappings from [META-INF/spring.schemas]
23:47:22,813 DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.PluggableSchemaResolver] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 23) Loaded schema mappings: {http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.3.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-4.3.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-2.5.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-4.2.xsd=org/springframework/cache/config/spring-cache-4.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.1.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-4.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd=org/springframework/web/servlet/config/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-3.0.xsd, http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/http-conf.xsd=schemas/configuration/http-conf.xsd, http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/parameterized-types=schemas/configuration/parameterized-types.xsd, http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd=schemas/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-4.3.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-3.2.xsd, http://www.w3.org/2006/07/ws-policy.xsd=schemas/ws-policy-200607.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-4.1.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-4.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-4.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/web/servlet/config/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-4.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-4.1.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-4.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/cache/config/spring-cache-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.1.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-4.1.xsd, http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/wsrm-manager.xsd=schemas/configuration/wsrm-manager.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.2.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task-4.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-4.3.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.2.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-4.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-4.1.xsd=org/springframework/cache/config/spring-cache-4.1.xsd, http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing=schemas/wsdl/addressing.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-4.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.0.xsd, http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd=schemas/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/web/servlet/config/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-2.5.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.3.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-4.3.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-4.0.xsd, http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/=schemas/wsdl/wsdl.xsd, http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/bindings/object.xsd=schemas/bindings/object.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd=org/springframework/web/servlet/config/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/web/servlet/config/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-4.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-4.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/cache/config/spring-cache-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-4.0.xsd, http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/jms.xsd=schemas/configuration/jms.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.1.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task-4.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-3.1.xsd, http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/=schemas/wsdl/http.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-4.1.xsd, http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/wsdl/jms.xsd=schemas/wsdl/jms.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/cache/config/spring-cache-4.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-3.1.xsd, http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd=schemas/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd, http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/parameterized-types.xsd=schemas/configuration/parameterized-types.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.2.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-4.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-4.3.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-3.0.xsd, http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/rm/wsrm-policy.xsd=schemas/configuration/wsrm-policy.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/web/servlet/config/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-4.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-4.3.xsd, [omitted for brevity]
23:47:22,813 DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.PluggableSchemaResolver] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 23) Found XML schema [http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd] in classpath: org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
23:47:22,828 DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.PluggableSchemaResolver] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 23) Found XML schema [http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd] in classpath: org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-4.3.xsd
23:47:22,828 DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.PluggableSchemaResolver] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 23) Found XML schema [http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-4.3.xsd] in classpath: org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-4.3.xsd
23:47:22,828 DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.PluggableSchemaResolver] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 23) Found XML schema [http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd] in classpath: org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-4.3.xsd
23:47:22,844 DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 23) Loading bean definitions
23:47:22,859 DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 23) Neither XML 'id' nor 'name' specified - using generated bean name [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#0]
23:47:22,875 DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 23) Loaded NamespaceHandler mappings: {http://www.springframework.org/schema/task=org.springframework.scheduling.config.TaskNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/p=org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.SimplePropertyNamespaceHandler, http://www.w3.org/2006/07/ws-policy=org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.spring.PolicyNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang=org.springframework.scripting.config.LangNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/util=org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.UtilNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/c=org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.SimpleConstructorNamespaceHandler, http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws=org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spring.NamespaceHandler, http://cxf.apache.org/policy=org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.spring.NamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee=org.springframework.ejb.config.JeeNamespaceHandler, http://cxf.apache.org/transports/jms=org.apache.cxf.transport.jms.spring.NamespaceHandler, http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration=org.apache.cxf.transport.http.spring.NamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx=org.springframework.transaction.config.TxNamespaceHandler,
```

which is correct (similar for infrastructure.xml).
Instead this message when processing **jboss-as-spring-mvc-context.xml**

```
   23:47:24,360 DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 23) Loading bean definitions
    23:47:24,361 DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 23) Loaded NamespaceHandler mappings: {}
```

2- When having the error #2 if I change xmlns:context in xmlns:context2 in **jboss-as-spring-mvc-context.xml** , we fall back in the error #1 .

3- This spring configuration infrastructure (with the 3 files ) is shipped with JBOSS Development Studio as a Maven SPring Project

4- The same spring configuration infrastructure does not have these problems with other projects

I'd like to solve the issue, event if it does not have practical consequences

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you missed a library with *.xsd files for one of used namespaces. Only in that case Spring will tries to load an xsd file from external url.

This article could help to understand the whole algorithm: http://blog.harmonysoft.tech/2010/01/spring-xsd-loading-algorithm.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it looks like all xsd are there. I checked spring.schemas and spring.handlers for the required xsd and everything seems good. I'll do a check again

Comment: Where exactly did you look? These XSDs  should be packed inside Spring jars, and jars could be on application level and on container level ( in JBoss/Wildfly common libs )

Comment: The XSD should be included with the spring-beans jar. Is it possible the jar is not being exported when the deployment runs?

Comment: i looked into the spring jars of the project (application level) and the xsd are there. They are not at container level in JOBSS EAP 6.3